# Add empty string between every string in a char array

Tags: arrays, matlab, char

I have a `char` array, and I want to insert a space in between each and every character.

```matlab
a = ['a','b','c','d']
```

I would like to have something like:

```matlab
a = ['a',' ','c',' ','d',' ']
```

Comment: In answering your question, i'd first point out that if you execute the second example code you wrote: ['a',''] results in 'a' because horzcat of 'a' and an empty removes the empty. Not sure what you're trying to accomplish overall, but you'll likely need to use cell array of char array or string as the type.

Comment: This solution is not proposed in the question marked as duplicate, you can use the kronecker product: `a = char(kron(a-32,[1,0])+32)`.

Comment: Ho, you can also use `a = char(kron(a+0,[1,0]))` it's simpler but the space will be replaced by the "NUL character" (ascii code = 0).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could first generate an array of empty chars and then filled it with your entries:

```
a = ['a','b','c','d'];
b = blanks(2*length(a));
b(1:2:end) = a;
```

Comment: Thanks! This works.